# can't able to generate pdf in lwc using pdflib

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation, jspdf, lwc

Here i am trying to create a pdf in salesforce using pdflib but when i click create pdf i got his error

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";
import PDFLib from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/pdflib";
import { loadScript } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";

export default class CreatePDF extends LightningElement {
    async connectedCallback() {
        await loadScript(this, PDFLib).then(() => {
        console.log('jsPDF script loaded successfully');
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error loading jsPDF library:', error);
    });
  }
  async createPdf() {
    console.log('inside generatePDF 19');
    const pdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.create();
    console.log('inside pdf');
    const timesRomanFont = await pdfDoc.embedFont(
      PDFLib.StandardFonts.TimesRoman
    );

    const page = pdfDoc.addPage();
    const { width, height } = page.getSize();
    const fontSize = 30;
    page.drawText("Learning with Salesforce Bolt !", {
      x: 50,
      y: height - 4 * fontSize,
      size: fontSize,
      font: timesRomanFont,
      color: PDFLib.rgb(0, 0.53, 0.71)
    });

    const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();
    this.saveByteArray("My PDF", pdfBytes);
  }
  saveByteArray(pdfName, byte) {
    var blob = new Blob([byte], { type: "application/pdf" });
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var fileName = pdfName;
    link.download = fileName;
    link.click();
  }
}
```

createPDF.js:50 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined